# iPhone interface examples

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to design a user interface for my iPhone app. It is going to be a simple form kind of look, which has around 8-9 labels and 1 textbox for user input and 1 button.

I am trying to design it in IB.
Can I get some good examples or tools online to create the interface.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have access to Interface Builder, then that's all the tool you need. What do you actually mean by an "online tool to create the interface"?

Comment: I wanted to know like which font styles, placement would look good and professional on the iPhone app?

Comment: Also to add, I am looking at simple design, but should look elegant.

Comment: Assuming "beginner" as a skill level, this might be useful: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-interface-builder-basic-training/

Comment: I know to use IB, but have never designed professional interfaces. So I am looking at some tips/examples to help me design simple, professional looking UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you do, start by reading the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: +1 So very, very, true. It'll *potentially* save a lot of pain and re-work further down the line.

Comment: I have already been through the guidelines. While it gives general idea about UI, I wanted to look at some specific examples of good UI designs

Comment: Look at the apps that you already have and that you think look nice and try to see what it is about them that make them look good.